# Detecting if image is glitch using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

How to detect a image is glitch or good using **OpenCV** ?

The **glitch** image maybe as the following:

[image]

Comment: Its not possible by hardcoding rules, as glitch as you mentioned doesn't have a common structure, it can be spread anywhere, Train a convolutional neural network that can classifiy the images to `glitch` and `not glitch`.

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN Do you have any papers or links about a convolutional neural network to classify the images to glitch or not ? Thanks

Comment: No, but i would suggest you to try this, use OpenCV to add disturbance to a set of images you have, you would be having two classes of images, one with noise, another without. Train the network on that.

Comment: You could check the horizontal color histogram for peaks in color space

Answer (score 0):

**No fancy Neural networks needed**, nowadays everyone seems to think NN are the only way to go. A glitch can be detected by histogram analysis. Usually every image has a very distinctive curve and you only need to detect if there are several variances. My approach to do something quite similar was.

## The General Idea

1. Convert to monochrome. Either you use the common `Luma = 0.299xRed + 0.587xGreen + 0.114xBlue`. Or you can do HSL or any other. Then you get a monochrome image. Futhermore ensure you have a standarized color, say 6 bit monochrome. Then you will have **only** 256 luminosity scales.
2. Discretize the image. You need to standarize a downscaled image, notice you don't even need the image to be rectangular. Say you downscale to 512x512. Choose the appropriate size for your application, or do some experiments.
3. Calculate slices. Of your MxM pixels image, just generate a bunch of NxN slices. Say for a 512x512 you get a 32x32 slice. Each one of 1024 pixels.
4. Calculate your histograms. In Mono8, this is the interesting part as you will get a bunch of values represeting each luminosity, you will get 256 values, each value in the range of 0 to 1024 (or 0 to 1). This can be seen as a color count: "For luminosity *x* you have *n* repetitions".
5. Discard based on your preferred histogram.

## ¿What the Histogram?

Histograms in commonly found images (like the one you have) are usually continuous or not so glitchy. And histograms on glitchy images have few teeth.

Below you can see the non glitchy part of your image.

[image: Image for the non-glitchy part]

And below is the glichy part:

[image: Glitchy part]

As you can see, there are significant peaks in Luma, but a per-plane histogram shows even more significan peaks on green and blue.

[image: Peaks]

And you can really notice the characteristic softer histogram of a common image.

[image: RGB Histogram]

## ¿How to detect a glitch?

So a glitch on an image can be reduced to an uncommon histogram. And this histogram would generally survive with very few differentes to scalings.

You would be surprised how a simplistic approach on a median, average or even a simple threshold on peaks can exclude **a lot** of glitchy images.

After you have a single channel o even the three channel histogram you just visually see the curves and I suggest you to apply a simple median. If the median is too high discard.

My approach was to generate medians of every slice, and then I had about 64 integers representing samples of the mosaic of slices. These mosaic should be "smooth" (by your own personal taste or your image samples). Just calculate an average, if some K slice is very far from it, the a glitch occured.

All these operations can be done in OpenCV. Pardon myself I do not wrote any code, but the algorithm should be easily inferred.